# Prove Vizing Class 1 if maximum degree vertices induce forest by induction

Tags: graph-theory

I tried to prove that if for a simple graph $G$, vertices of maximum degree induce a forest, then $\chi'(G) \leq \Delta(G)$, in other words, the graph is in Vizing Class 1.

When I applied induction on $|E(G)|$, I encountered the problem, that if there is only one vertex $v \in V(G)$ having maximum degree, I cannot ensure that I can apply the induction hypothesis on $G\setminus e$ for an edge $e$ incident with $v$.

If I remove $e$, there might be vertices of degree $\Delta(G) - 1$ inducing a cycle. [This graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrLIi.png) is an example. If we remove the degree 5 vertex, then the degree 4 vertices don't induce a forest.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to fix this proof?

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009600/let-g-be-a-simple-graph-whose-vertices-of-maximum-degree-delta-induce-a-fo?rq=1

Comment: i tried to do the same, but i think there is a problem there. I can't apply the induction hypothesis, because $v$ might be the only vertex having maximum degree

Comment: the proof still applies. In the case of only one vertex, just remove any edge incident with it.

Comment: i added an example now - i am worried that the induction hypothesis does not hold if i remove any edge incident with it

Comment: What you need is that,  $G$ \ $e$ has a proper edge coloring with at most $\Delta(G)$ colors

Answer (score -1):

if the maximum degree of G\e is not Δ(G),then Δ(G\e)+1≤Δ(G) and by Vizing there is a Δ(G) edge coloring. Thats all you need